# WCF Restful service file upload with multi-platform support

Tags: c#, android, iphone, .net, wcf

can anybody please tell me how can i create a WCF Rest service through which i can be abel to upload files to server using android , iphone & WP7.

Comment: if possible please provide working example or resource. i am new to wcf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for help I was able to create file upload wcf rest service for multiple platform.

```
public void FileUpload(string fileName, Stream fileStream)
{
    FileStream fileToupload = new FileStream("c:\\FileUpload\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);

    byte[] bytearray = new byte[10000];
    int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
    do
    {
        bytesRead = fileStream.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    } while (bytesRead > 0);

    fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
    fileToupload.Close();
    fileToupload.Dispose();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IImageUpload
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "FileUpload/{fileName}")]
    void FileUpload(string fileName, Stream fileStream); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. can you please post the android code that you used to upload an image to this code?

Comment: could you tell me the way to access this service from android device

Answer (score 2):

Any `Rest service` can be accessed using Android, iphone and WP7.

One option is to create a Rest POST service using `WCF` or `MVC` and get the image in `data` as base64 string.