# Android Image upload to C# .NET REST service

Tags: c#, android, .net, rest, image-uploading

I know this question has been asked a lot on stackoverflow and its all over the internet, but it seems that there is never a common or best solution to upload an image from multi-platform to .NET REST service.

I have found this solution from a question asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978961/wcf-restful-service-file-upload-with-multi-platform-support) for the service side, my first question is, What is the best and most optimized way to upload an image from Android to that specific service specified in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978961/wcf-restful-service-file-upload-with-multi-platform-support) ?

My second question is, how can i add a JSON with data to accompany the image being uploaded? I have seen solutions of appending the data in header param and not as a JSON? what is the perfect way to do that ?

Comment: Do you want to upload your image from Android to FTP server ?

Comment: I wanna upload the image to my http server not FTP, using the code that i linked in the question

Comment: You shouldn't place anything to image bytearray, maybe after while loop you can send another string which means **Sending is OK**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have few proposals while uploading file to web service:

1. Write a web serivice that allow multi part file upload using [MultipartFormDataStreamProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatastreamprovider%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)
2. Dont read the whole file content while uploading to web service. Rather use HttpClient library to upload mutiple part content. See [MultipartEntity](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html).

   ```
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("Service URL");
   FileBody body1 = new FileBody(new File(path), mimeType);
   MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
   reqEntity.addPart("part0", body1);
   httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
   ```
3. Use android background service when uploading file. If it is big file then it will take long time to upload. If the app went to backgournd
   then upload process might be internupted.
4. In the server side you need a custom implementation of MultipartFileStreamProvider class to pass additional file attributes.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding your 1st question:**

The "best" way to upload an image from android, pretty much depends on your situation, eg:

- If you were handling sensitive photos, the "best" way might be to upload over SSL to be more secure
- Uploading multiple photos? Maybe an aggregated compression-upload-decompression method would suffice.

Basically what I'm saying is, use the most obvious method for you specific needs.

**Regarding question 2:**

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258932/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-using-javascript-only-to-store-image-on-sql-s) question.

You can use the getBase64Image method to get the image bytes on the client side and then pop that into your json you send to the server

Comment: for the 1st question, not secure i want the regular one image upload, do u have any code example for the c# code that i attached?

Comment: Thanks for the second answer

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of a file upload using wcf rest:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IUploader
{
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "FileUpload?public_id={public_id}&tags={tags}",
  Method = "POST",
  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
  UploadImageResult UploadImage(Stream fileContents, string public_id, string tags);
}

public class Uploader : IUploader
{
public UploadImageResult UploadImage(Stream fileContents, string public_id, string tags)
{
try
{
byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
FileStream fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(rootFolderPath, @"test\test.jpg"));
int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
do
{
bytesRead = fileContents.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
} while (bytesRead > 0);

fs.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
...
}
}
}
```

To call using c#

```
// Create the REST URL. 
string requestUrl = @"http://localhost:2949/fileupload?public_id=id&tags=tags";
//file to upload make sure it exist
string filename = @"C:\temp\ImageUploaderService\vega.jpg";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
request.Method = "POST";
//request.ContentType = "text/plain";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
byte[] fileToSend = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
request.ContentLength = fileToSend.Length;
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
 {
 // Send the file as body request. 
 requestStream.Write(fileToSend, 0, fileToSend.Length);
 requestStream.Close();
}

 using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
 {
    Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", response.ProtocolVersion,     (int)response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription);
    string text;
     using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                    dynamic testObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);

                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("response url is {0}", testObj.url));
                }
```

Question #2, you can just append the data using a key/value pair on the url of the request like in the example.

Hope that will help.

Comment: hey man thanks for the answer but i was looking for android code and not C#(.net)

Comment: No worries, but i think from there you can get idea how to convert it to java. Java is used in android right?